# Two different git installations, only need to use one

Tags: git, path, .bash-profile

I'm on a shared hosting account with a jailed shell and I'm terrible with $PATH. I'm using CentOS. Originally my host installed git in `/usr/local/bin` which didn't work out correctly, I suggested install git in my `$HOME/opt/bin` and it works perfectly. However, now there are two git installations. Using `which git` yields the `/usr/local/bin/git` installation. How can I modify my current PATH to use my `$HOME/opt/bin/git` without taking away `/usr/local/bin/git`?

Here is my current `~/.bash_profile`:
`export PATH=/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/lib/courier-imap/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The directories listed in the PATH environment variable are searched from first to last (left to right) when running external programs.

For your purpose you will want to have `"$HOME"/opt/bin` before (to the left of) `/usr/local/bin`. If your PATH value was constructed like this:

```
export PATH=/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/lib/courier-imap/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin/
```

then you could use this instead:

```
export PATH="$HOME"/opt/bin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/lib/courier-imap/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin/
```

(i.e. have `"$HOME"/opt/bin` be the very first PATH entry).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `:$HOME/opt/bin/git` to the path.

Comment: No dice :(, results in:


-jailshell-3.2$ nano ~/.bash_profile
-jailshell-3.2$ source ~/.bash_profile
-jailshell-3.2$ which git
/usr/local/bin/git